# Cox proportional hazard model has very small hazard ratio, s.error and no CI

Tags: regression, stata, cox-model

I estimate a Cox proportional model in Stata to see what covariates are associated with time to death. One of the covariates measure cormobidities and has 12 categories. One of the categories ("Leukemia") has 0 events and hence low Hazard ratio, standard error and no confidence intervals calculated.
HR = 7.03e-21; SE = 1.52e-11; lower limit of CI = 0 and upper is (.)

Any suggestions 1) how to report these results 2) how to treat this issue (e.q group the category with no events with another category with events, even few, into a new one "Cormobitidy A or B"? 3) can people publish when one category of a variable has no events and so low HR?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I guess you included these categories as a set of dummy variables (excluding the baseline). Then 'Leukemia' is simply treated as a constant because it does not vary within the risk set. It is a form of collinearity. Hence, the coefficient cannot be estimated.
With regard to your last questions, if you are running a Cox model, it means you are interested in death/survival. Since 'Leukemia' is not associated with any event, it is not a covariate of interest. I would either redefine the risk set or exclude it from the analysis, motivating this choice e.g. with some descriptive statistics. I think this is much neater than simply pooling it with other categories or with the baseline itself. If Leukemia should be of interest (depending on your study/field), you may then add some thoughts on why this is not the case in your sample.